# AccessViolationException when using WP8.1 MapControl.SetLocation() method

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, windows-runtime, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT application (Universal App), which is based on `MapControl` control.

The problem with it is that, for unknown reasons to me, when I call `MapControl.SetLocation()` method, I get `AccessViolationException`. It does not always happen - in fact I've been using that method for quite a long time and everything was fine. But now I'm developing new functionality - it boils down to porting code from MSDN (pushpin clustering) - [MSDN Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Clustering-Pushpins-in-95fb729a#content). Code contains some callback logic, some async/await usages. The problem is in mentioned earlier `SetLocation()`. I don't know why it throws exceptions.

What I've tried:

1. I'm working with MVVMLight, so experimented a lot with `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI()`. Nothing.
2. Tried to make sure whether creating the pushpin object happens in UI thread - I don't know how to do that in the debugger (shall I check the tasks windows, or the threads window).

I don't post any code, because, as you can imagine, it's quite a lot of it - and I don't know if that would be any of use. So, my question is, do you know what might cause throwing `AccessViolationException` when invoking `CheckBeginInvokeOnUI`? Maybe there are some kind of constraints that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Can you build a small sample that exhibits this behavior and add it to the question?

Comment: Try using `DispatherHelper.RunAsync()`. I'd guess it would work.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yeah, of course - I will do that tonight after work. @yasen I tried `DispatherHelper.RunAsync()` - the results were the same. `Dispatcher` helped when the problem was strictly connected with using Tasks. I.e. calling `await Task.Run(() => MapControl.SetLocation(...)` resulted with `Exception: RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD`. Wrapping lambda expression with `DispatcherHelper` resolves that issue, but that's not the case. I'm having problem not with the WRONG_THREAD, but with the `AccessViolationException`.

Comment: @Malutek In most cases you get `AccessViolationException` when you try to access something UI-related from another thread. Did you wrap only the line that throws the exception in the RunAsync() method? If not - please try that.

Comment: Yeah, but what does it mean that it's UI related? I've tried to both wrap the line that throws the exception and to wrap the whole clustering method with the `DisptacherHelper.RunAsync()` method. It did not help.